# JSON invalid character on line 1 error message on deployed software?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting the above error message on deployed software, my issue is that the error does not appear when running off the localhost.

I have checked to see if valid data is entered into the json on both the local host and the server, yet I am still getting this error because the json.parse is trying to parse html. I am at a loss can anybody help me figure out what is going on with my json between my controller and my javascript??

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult UserStatuses_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string userName)
{
    try
    {
        throw new DivideByZeroException();

        return Json("Hello World");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ExceptionContext filterContext = new ExceptionContext();
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return Json(new
        {
            errorCode = (HttpContext.Response.StatusCode),
            Title = "Error",
            Details = e.Message
        });
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function onError(args, status) {
    var kendoNotification = $("#Notification").data("kendoNotification");
    var errorMessage = JSON.parse(args.xhr.responseText);
    kendoNotification.show({
        title: errorMessage.Title,
        message: errorMessage.Details
    }, "error");
};
```

**Extra Information:** The code above is supposed to show a notification when there is an error thrown. As I mentioned above this works well when running through the local host but when running through our server the data the is being parsed is the html code shown below. why is my error notifications causing an error? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**HTML from the JSON:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">
    <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>
        <title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
        <style type=\"text/css\"><!--
            body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
           fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
           h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
           h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
           h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
           #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
           background-color:#555555;}
           #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
           .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
        --></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
        <div id=\"content\">
            <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>
                <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
                <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
            </fieldset></div>
         </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you used fiddler to check the response differences from localhost vs the remote server?  Are the responses the same?

Comment: I have never used fiddler, I was just emailing the responses to myself to get the controller side information then using firebug to get the returned data. I can say that the code being sent is the same but the code that is received is different.

Comment: @wigs I have just looked at fiddler and it looks like the remote servers response doesn't actually send any json, there is a HTML response but no json, any ideas how to figure out what is happening?

Comment: What information is in the HTML response?  Also, I know this is silly but are you positive the remote and local code is identical?

Comment: @wigs The Html response is shown above, and is just the error message.I know the fix to the error the message is from but I do not know why the json is being replaced by javascript. Also I have been checking the code and I can't see anything different at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you throw a 500 error iis wraps everything that is returned in html so your json will be lost inside the html.

Try adding the followng line of code bellow where you set the error code.

`Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;`

This should force your json through and allow you to use it in your own custom error handler.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your responses, I am going to say that the path on your localhost is different than that on your remote server.  When you are running code on local web servers, the path is typically something like http://localhost:port/page/parameters.  However, when your code is running on the remote server the path is similar to http://servername/applicationname/page/parameters.

Check to make sure that any links (images, pages, etc) on views and in javascript have a way to prepend the application name to them in order for them to work on the localhost and the remote server.

Comment: Exactly, using the developer tools in your browser can you provide a general idea of what the links are when the paged is viewed from the localhost vs the remote server?  Also, what would the actual urls be if you were to manually type them into your browser.

Comment: The 2 urls are as follows: localhost: `http://localhost:port/controller/action?parameters` remote server: `http://systemName.co.uk/controller/action?parameters` This doesn't look like there is much difference here?

Comment: Also I am certain the action is being hit by the remote server.

Comment: Do you have access to that remote server?  What custom error settings do you have currently for that application?  If you don't have remote errors on, can you either test directly on the server or turn remote errors on, access the page and then turn remote errors off?

Comment: Yes I have access to the server. We have a custom error page if the view fails to load else if something on the page fails due to ajax this notification is supposed to show the error. However when the notification fails the user will think it is 'hanging'. I will try looking at the error settings.